# Convergence of the "remainder" of a series of permuted products

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(\lambda_j)$ be a monotonically decreasing sequence of positive numbers converging to zero but so that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j=\infty$, and let $(u_j)$ be an arbitrary sequence of non-negative real numbers. Assume that
$$
\sup_\sigma\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_{\sigma(j)}u_j<\infty,
$$
where the supremum is taken over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\mathbb N$.

> **Question:** Is it always true that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_\sigma\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_{\sigma(j)}u_{j+n}\right)=0?
> $$

I really have no idea if this is true or not. Note that
$$
\sup_\sigma\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_{\sigma(j)}u_{j+n}=\sup_\sigma\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\lambda_{\sigma(j-n)}u_{j}
$$
and so the whole thing reminds me of the fact that the remainder of a convergent series goes to 0. However, I do not know how to handle the shifting that is done by the permutation. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remark: $\sum \lambda_j u_{\tau(j)}$ is maximized when the permutation $\tau$ is chosen so that $u_{\tau(j)}$ is also in decreasing order; in your notation, $\sigma$ is the inverse to $\tau$.

Comment: Note that by permuting the $u_j$, you can assume the $u_j$ are in decreasing order—as long as, in your last sum, the $u_j$ are "evicted" not in the order $j=1,2,\dots$ but in an arbitrary order (the order they were in before that permutation). However, your assumption implies that $u_j\to0$, and so every term will get evicted in finite time. Therefore your problem reduces to: if both $\lambda_j$ and $u_j$ are decreasing, and $\sum \lambda_j u_j$ converges, does $\sum \lambda_j u_{j+n}$ tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: And then the answer is yes. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $\sum_N^\infty\lambda_ju_j < \epsilon/2$ and then choose $n$ such that $u_{n+1}\sum_1^{N-1}\lambda_j < \epsilon/2$. Then$$\sum_1^\infty\lambda_ju_{j+n} = \sum_1^{N-1}\lambda_ju_{j+n} + \sum_N^\infty\lambda_ju_{j+n}\le u_{n+1}\sum_1^{N-1}\lambda_j + \sum_N^\infty\lambda_ju_j < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much for this nice solution. Please write this as an answer, I will accept it. However, could you please elaborate why we can indeed assume that both sequences are decreasing? To be honest, I do not really understand the "evicted" argument...